# phpRegEx: replace everything except ASCII and UTF8 numbers

Tags: php, regex, unicode, replace, ascii

How can I replace everything except ASCII/unicode numbers:

ASCII
**0-9**
Unicode:
**٠-٩**

Using PHP::RegEx, any ideas what code I need?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\P{Nd}` to specify “any character that is not a decimal digit”:

```
preg_replace('/\P{Nd}/u', '', $s)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ret = preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $str);
```

Comment: At the very least you'll need the `u` modifier. But even then I'm not sure that the default character classes are Unicode-aware (documentation on that is silent, though).

Comment: @xdazz thanks, but doesn't work correctly. Output-> ١١١���٢٢٢